# In which in esperanto

Tags: translation

In Persian we say "که در آن", meaning "in which". If I were to translate it directly from Persian to Esperanto, it would be "ke en tio". So can I translate it this way?

Comment: Ne. "ke, en tio" estas io alia. 'ke' enkondukas subfrazon. Ekzemple: *mi eĉ estas preta konsenti, ke en tio vi estas prava.* (Patroj kaj filoj, Kabe).

Comment: "en kio" would make sense too. Maybe give some sentences.

Comment: Maybe "kie" (where) or "pri kio" (about which)

Comment: @JoopEggen, for example, "Sinestezio estas neŭrologia fenomeno en kiu du aŭ pluraj sensoj asociiĝas." Can I use "ke en tio" instead of "en kiu"?

Comment: Ĉe "fenomeno" _en kiu_ laŭ nacilingva uzo estas komprenebla, _kie_ (loko, areo) aŭ _ĉe_ pli logika

Comment: "ke en tio" ne konvenas. "... signifas ke en tio" - do sen "fenomeno".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vortaro_angla-Esperanto proponas ekzemplojn de frazoj kun "in which" ...

https://eo.wiktionary.org/wiki/Aldono:Vortaro_angla-Esperanto

Serĉu (supre dekstre) "in which".

Vidu la ekzemplojn sub 'Aldono: Vortaro angla-Esperanto'